# Where is input temporarily stored during "bq load .. localfile.csv"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

The gcloud-sdk command "bq load" can take a local file as input.

From the output of the command, it looks like that file is first being uploaded into google cloud storage *somewhere* before the bigquery load job is scheduled. Given that the REST api for bigquery schedule-load-job endpoint also takes only "gs://" urls, and that the load-job needs the data to be *reachable*, I am pretty sure that such an upload to cloud-storage is taking place (though I can't find any documentation that explicitly describes "bq load" with local files.

My question then is: can someone tell me *where* the local file is temporarily uploaded to? Is it one of the gcloud project cloud-storage buckets, or somewhere else? Is it guaranteed to be deleted after the load-job completes?

I have a requirement for data to be kept only in a specific geographical region, thus the location of the (presumed) temporary storage is significant.

I could upload the data explicitly to storage, then use "bq load" with a reference to the cloud storage, but then need to arrange deletion of the data afterwards which is a minor inconvenience. A dedicated storage with a "lifecycle rule" could at least delete after 1 day, but the "bq load .. localfile" approach is cleaner..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `bq --help` you can see how one of the `global bq_flags` is `--location`. It is defined as follows:

> --location:  “Default geographic location to use when creating datasets or determining where jobs should run  (Ignored when not
>   applicable.)”

If you run:

```
bq load --location=eu {your-table} {your-source}
```

For a dataset located in EU, then the job should succeed and all jobs related should be run in EU.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, the --location flag isn't documented clearly enough to satisfy my use-case. My customer has stated clearly in the project requirements that at no time should data be stored outside of the EU. With this flag it is possible to specify "--location=eu" (note: this is what Google elsewhere refers to as a "multi-regional location" or "multi-region name"). However the bq tool still just prints out "uploaded", with no confirmation of where the data was loaded to. The location flag could possibly be specifying where the load-job runs, but not where the data is stored.

Comment: The gcloud commands all support a "--verbosity=" flag; if bq had this then it might possibly print out where the data is being uploaded to. However the bq command apparently lacks this flag. Given the vague behaviour of "bq load" with local files, and a legal requirement to use eu storage, I'll just have to fall back to using "gsutil cp" then "bq load" from cloud-storage. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SimonKitching Kitching, see that actually when you create your dataset you choose where it’s located (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets). If you choose EU: “your Core BigQuery Customer Data resides in the EU. ” Core Bigquery Data is defined here: https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms#13-google-bigquery-service .The  13.2 Transient Storage article states “...Data may be stored transiently or cached in any country”, but if your dataset location is EU it means that it will be located in any country in EU.

Comment: @SimonKitching ,Continuing from my answer, if you set --location=eu, all jobs will be run in EU and data will be stored there if your Dataset had EU set as Data Location. To be sure about this try the following: Using a Dataset with data location set to EU, try to run: `bq load --location=us {} {}`. It'll fail; you can only run jobs for this Dataset in EU (so actually it looks it is not even neccesary to set this flag if your dataset is located in EU)